# Getting only one attrubute when passing an array of class objects?

Tags: python, arrays, class, object, oop

I'm trying to filter stock based on marketcap and I want to set a list of stock as the class objects, so I pass the array with the ticker symbols as objects. But I am only getting one 'False', when I expect it to return two boolean values (since there are two stocks).

How can I modify the following codes so that I can get cond_1 attributes for all items in a list. (e.g. AAPL.cond_1 = False, GOOG.cond_1 = False)?

```
top_gainer_list = ['AAPL', 'GOOG']


class gainers():
    def __init__(self, cond_1):
        self.cond_1 = cond_1


    def filter_marketCap(self):
        backup_list1 = []
        iexresponse = requests.get(
            "https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols={}&types=quote&token=APIKEY".format(
                ','.join(top_gainer_list)))
        data = iexresponse.json()
        for ticker in top_gainer_list:
            marketCap = int(data[ticker]['quote']['marketCap'])
            if 10000000 <= marketCap <= 200000000:
                self.cond_1 = True
            else:
                self.cond_1 = False


top_gainer = gainers(top_gainer_list)
top_gainer.filter_marketCap()
print(top_gainer.cond_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look -

```
self.cond_1 = False


top_gainer = gainers(top_gainer_list)
top_gainer.filter_marketCap()
print(top_gainer.cond_1)
```

You are printing the `self.cond_1`. So only the later value gets printed. To get around this issue, use print statements in the method itself -

```
if 10000000 <= marketCap <= 200000000:
                print(True)
            else:
                print(False)
```

Just change the line as shown, you will get 2 results.
Do not use print again down. Just call the method -

```
   top_gainer = gainers(top_gainer_list)
   top_gainer.filter_marketCap()
```

Comment: Is there a way I can get the cond_1 values for all items in the list when I call the function?

Comment: I didn't get you. This prints for all the items in the list